# Dynamically navigating through n categories

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm trying to create my first iOS project. I have quite well experiences with C#. I receive data with categories and articles. But I don't know, how many subcategories I will get, before the articles will be listed. The browsing though the subcategories should be done via TableView. When a User clicks a category, the subcategories (level 1) should be displayed in a tableView. Then, after touching a subcategory, the subcategories (level 2) of present should be displayed (and so on). Lastly, when there are no further subcategories, the article-list should be displayed. After touching one article, a new ViewController with the article-data should be displayed.

My question is, how to handle the navigation through the subcategories and creating segues or sth. like that. I know, that I can't use storyboard for this, because I don't know the number of subcategories and they also differ.

How can I achieve this dynamic navigation? Can you give me an example? I know how to populate data to the tableView. Only the dynamic navigation is the problem.

Comment: what about defining categories and articles in database , and fetch them during run time?

Comment: I receive this data via an API over WAN/LAN. But getting the data is not that problem. I don't know how to programmatically reuse the tableviewcontroller with n subcategory-levels and a final article level. I thought of sth like this in concept: Display data in table. Touch -> display subcategories level one with reuse this table (and navigation stack) -> touch -> display -> touch -> display .... lastly display article-list -> touch -> load UIViewController with article Details. How do I do this via code. Is this the right way? Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have a solution. Can someone please check, if I am doing it correctly not that I don't violate programming patterns or guidelines.

In short: In TableSource-Class I access the Storyboard and dynamically create and show the same Controller which actually is presented. But before presenting the new one, I declare an other source-class. So the TableView is used for displaying Addressbooks and Addresscards, the UIViewController is used for displaying the carddata. These two controllers are connected via segue.

Here are my Controller and both Source-Classes:

AddressbooksController.cs

```
public AddressbooksController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        displayModel = "addressbooks";
    }

    private void loadAddressbooks()
    {
        var AppDelegate = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
        addressbooks = AppDelegate.api.DeserializeEntities<YAddressbook>(Task.Run(async () => await AppDelegate.api.Get("Yaddressbooks")).Result);
    }

    public void loadAddresscards()
    {
        var AppDelegate = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
        addresscards = AppDelegate.api.DeserializeEntities<Ycard>(Task.Run(async () => await AppDelegate.api.Get("Ycards")).Result);
    }

    public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);

        // do first a control on the Identifier for your segu
        if (segue.Identifier.Equals("segueShowAddress"))
        {

            var viewController = (AddresscardController)segue.DestinationViewController;
            viewController.card = Card2Display;
        }
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        if (displayModel == "addressbooks")
        {
            loadAddressbooks();
            tableView.Source = new AddressbooksTableSource(addressbooks.data, this);
            this.NavigationController.Title = "Addressbücher";
        }
        else if (displayModel == "addresscards")
        {
            loadAddresscards();
            tableView.Source = new AddresscardsTableSource(addresscards.data, this);
            this.NavigationController.
        }

        base.ViewDidLoad();
    }
```

AddressbooksTableSource

```
public class AddressbooksTableSource: UITableViewSource
{

    private List<YAddressbook> addressbooks;
    private string cellIdentifier = "AddressbooksCell";
    private UINavigationController navigationController;


    public AddressbooksTableSource(List<YAddressbook> books, AddressbooksController ab)
    {
        addressbooks = books;
        this.navigationController = ab.ParentViewController as UINavigationController;
        Console.WriteLine(ab.displayModel);
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Row selected" + addressbooks[indexPath.Row].displayname);
        UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);

        AddressbooksController newab = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("AddressbooksViewController") as AddressbooksController;
        newab.displayModel = "addresscards";
        navigationController.PushViewController(newab, true);

        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
    }


    ....
}
```

AddresscardsTableSource

```
public class AddresscardsTableSource: UITableViewSource
{
    private List<Ycard> addresscards;
    UINavigationController navigationController;
    AddressbooksController ab;
    string cellIdentifier = "AddresscardCell";

    public AddresscardsTableSource(List<Ycard> cards, AddressbooksController vc)
    {
        addresscards = cards;
        navigationController = vc.ParentViewController as UINavigationController;
        ab = vc;
        //navigationController = tableview;
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Row selected" + addresscards[indexPath.Row].carddata);
        //UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);

        ab.Card2Display = addresscards[indexPath.Row];
        ab.PerformSegue("segueShowAddress", indexPath);

        //AddresscardController ab = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("AddresscardViewController") as AddressbooksController;
        //ab.TableView.Source = this;
        //navigationController.PushViewController(ab, true);

        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
    }

    .....

}
```

It works. But am I doing it correctly? Thanks